# Regex to parse an IRC-style /me emote?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to come up with a regex that matches:

```
/me slaps John around with a trout
```

and outputs

```
Group 1: /me
Group 2: slaps John around with a trout
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: What are the "rules" of the regex? also you should try some yourself :p

Comment: `(\S+)\s(.*)` Criteria met.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along the lines of

```
^(\/me) (.*)$
```

Answer (score 0):

your regex for this is
**(/me)\s+(.*?)$**

```
(/me)   << first group
\s+     << then one or more whitespace
(.*?)   << second group, one or more characters
$       << end of line
```